# Streaming-download a xml file from s3, get a empty file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I was trying to download a xml file from s3 bucket using AWS-SDK, but I keep getting an empty xml file for some reason.

Here is my code for this part:

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
obj = s3.buckets['data']
viglink_data=obj.objects['data.xml']

File.open('app/assets/data.xml', 'wb') do |file|
    viglink_data.read do |chunk|
        file.write(chunk)
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not ruby user but read this doc that may help you : http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx354Y6VTZ421PJ/Downloading-Objects-from-Amazon-S3-using-the-AWS-SDK-for-Ruby